# Class 'Memcached' not found in MemcachedConnector.php (line 69)

Tags: laravel, memcached

I am trying to use memcached in my laravel project i have set in **cache.php**

```
'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            //'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
           /* 'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
            ],*/
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
```

and also install memcached in my windows server when i check the status of memcached it is showing me running.

then i also inable the extension=memcache.dll in **my xampp php.ini** file when i test the memcache in my normal project without any framework

```
$m = new Memcache;
$m->connect('localhost', 11211);
$m->set("str_key", "String to store in memcached");
var_dump($m->get('str_key'));
```

above code is working fine when i just try to check my memcache it is showing me the result.

then i have tried to use laravel memcached in my project then it is showing me

```
public function index(){

        //echo "test";
        Cache::store('memcached')->put('bar', 'baz', 10);
    }
```

this is showing me **Class 'Memcached' not found
in MemcachedConnector.php (line 69)**
anyone have idea how to use this in laravel . Thank You in advance

Comment: Those are 2 different extensions, `Memcache !== Memcached`.

Comment: yes i know there are two extention in core php we can use memcache and it is working properly in core php but when i go with laravel it is using memcached and i have spent much more time to search memcached.dll but not found yet do you have any idea for windows (Memcached.dll)